# ajax post data doesn't return match value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax:

```
  function showDetil(terit) {

        $("#detilpie").html("<h1 style='margin-top:300px;'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw'></i><span class='sr-only'>Loading...</span></h1>");
    var fp = 'PE';
    $.ajax({
        url: "data/datadetilpie.php",
        data: {terit: terit, famprod: fp},
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            $("#detilpie").html(data);
            $('#datapie').DataTable();
        }
    });
}
```

Then in datadetilpie.php I catch the data:

```
$terit = ucwords(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'terit'));
$famprod= ucwords(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'famprod'));
die($famprod);
```

Anyone knows why when I debug in inspect, the die($famprod); always returns 'Kw'? It should return 'PE' as I described a var above the ajax. Good solution will be appreciate.

Comment: How can this piece of code return 'Kw' that is not defined anywhere here!..

Comment: @d3vdpro thats why I ask here

Comment: @RatHat because in the actual code in datadetilpie.php i have created a table in html. My requirement the ajax returns the html data.

Comment: If `terit` variable doesn't have , it will not run your ajax

Comment: @DavidJawphan my question has been edited. terit comes from the parameter of function showDetil(terit)

Comment: Have you searched for 'Kw' in your code?

Comment: @thiru right now I am on searching...

Comment: I have done it, the 'kw' comes from another file. Actually, that function runs when I click the piece of piechart. I have 6 pie charts. All charts always use the ajax writen in piekw.php. Because I found that all function in each file has same name 'showDetil'. Then now I have edited all function name. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with basic echo first before call to other functions like ucwords and filer_input..etc.

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['famprod'];
?>
```

Comment: did you check on javascript console...?

Answer (score 0):

The 'kw' comes from another file. Actually, that function runs when I click the piece of piechart. I have 6 pie charts. But the problem I found that all charts always execute the ajax writen in piekw.php. After I searched, I found that all function in each file has same name 'showDetil'. Thats the problem. Then now I have edited all function name. Now, All runs well. Thanks all for your help.